# can't do hard reset

Tags: nexus-7, hard-reset

I have Nexus 7 from 2012. Some time ago I had problem with it and did hard-reset.

For several months it worked fine, but now it just restarting all the time.

I can't even go to Recovery Mode, pressing Volume Down and Power doesn't have any effect.

Do I have any other options before throwing it out?